# JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'Long'. BsonArray.Deserialize. Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb, deserialization, bson

I know there are possible duplicates. But I've been looking at these questions. There they have a function, then aggregation. But this is the usual answer from mongo shell.
I got this result from mongo shell

```
[
{
_id: ObjectId("5da08d49949b4c000100b90b"), 
ModifiedOn: ISODate("2019-10-11T14:10:17.461Z"), 
UniqueNumber: Long("22635664")
}
]
```

I tried to do the following

```
BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(string)
```

But I get this

```
JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'Long'.
```

What can i do? Apparently this is not the correct Bson format. But if I remove this string `UniqueNumber: Long("22635664")`. Then everything works. What should I do?

By the way. I can't use custom classes. Because json will change.
This result is output from `mongosh`. But if i will use `mongo` then it will parse.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, the shell type is named `NumberLong` which works well here

Comment: I know. NumberLong from "mongo". But i am using "mongosh"